# With python-oracledb what does 'DPY-4027: no configuration directory to search for tnsnames.ora' mean

Tags: python, database, oracle, python-oracledb

1. With the [python-oracledb](https://oracle.github.io/python-oracledb/) driver the code:

   ```
   import oracledb

   cs = "MYDB"
   c = oracledb.connect(user='cj', password=mypw, dsn=cs)
   ```

   gives the error:

   ```
   oracledb.exceptions.DatabaseError: DPY-4027: no configuration directory to search for tnsnames.ora
   ```
2. The same error also occurs in a second case:

   ```
   import oracledb

   cs = "MYDB = (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=orclpdb1)))"
   c = oracledb.connect(user='cj', password=mypw, dsn=cs)
   ```

   and with this:

   ```
   import oracledb

   cs = "MYDB = (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=orclpdb1)))"

   cp = oracledb.ConnectParams()
   cp.parse_connect_string(cs)
   ```

What does this mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error means you used a connection string that python-oracledb took to be some kind of alias it needed to look up in a `tnsnames.ora` file, but it didn't know where to find that file.

Database connection strings in python-oracledb can be one of:

- An Oracle Easy Connect string like `myhost:1521/orclpdb1`
- An Oracle Net Connect Descriptor string like `(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(...))`
- A Net Service Name alias mapping to a connect descriptor.  These connect descriptors are commonly stored in a 'tnsnames.ora' file on the machine where you are running Python.  They may also be accessed from an LDAP server.

See the user documentation on [connection strings](https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/connection_handling.html#connection-strings)

If the connection string is an alias, or is not recognized as an Easy Connect string or Connect Descriptor, then you must have a [`tnsnames.ora` configuration file](https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/initialization.html#optional-oracle-net-configuration-files) that maps the alias to a connect descriptor.  The `tnsnames.ora` file might look like:

```
MYDB = (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=orclpdb1)))
```

**Case 1**:

```
import oracledb

cs = "MYDB"
c = oracledb.connect(user='cj', password=mypw, dsn=cs)
```

To use this connection string, you need to tell python-oracledb where to find the `tnsnames.ora` file that contains the mapping from the alias `MYDB` to the connect descriptor that really tells Oracle where the DB is located. (See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73211052/4799035) for why).

If you have a file `/opt/myconfigdir/tnsnames.ora`, then in python-oracledb's default 'Thin' mode you can do this:

```
import oracledb

cs = "MYDB"
c = oracledb.connect(user='cj', password=mypw, dsn=cs, config_dir='/opt/myconfigdir')
```

Note that even if `ORACLE_HOME` is set, Thin mode will not automatically read `$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin/tnsnames.ora`.  You must explicitly tell python-oracledb (in Thin mode) where to read the file from.

In the Thick mode (which is the mode when the app calls `init_oracle_client()`), if the `tnsnames.ora` file is *not* put in a default location, then you can tell python-oracledb where to find it like:

```
import oracledb

oracledb.init_oracle_client(config_dir='/opt/myconfigdir')

cs = "MYDB"
c = oracledb.connect(user='cj', password=mypw, dsn=cs)
```

In both modes you can alternatively set the environment variable `TNS_ADMIN` to the directory containing the file, and then run Python. See the configuration file link above for more information.

**Case 2:**

```
import oracledb

cs = "MYDB = (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=orclpdb1)))"
c = oracledb.connect(user='cj', password=mypw, dsn=cs)
```

This is a pure "typo".  What was passed as the connection string is a string containing *both* a net service name alias and the connect descriptor, which is the syntax used in [`tnsnames.ora` configuration files](https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/initialization.html#optional-oracle-net-configuration-files), not in applications themselves.

Python-oracledb didn't understand this syntax and assumed you were trying to pass a net service name alias.  It needed to look this up in a `tnsnames.ora` file, but failed to locate such a file.

A solution is to pass only the connect descriptor component without the `MYDB =` part. For example like:

```
import oracledb

cs = "(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=orclpdb1)))"
c = oracledb.connect(user='cj', password=mypw, dsn=cs)
```

Or you can put the original, whole string in a `tnsnames.ora` file and then call:

```
import oracledb

cs = "MYDB"
c = oracledb.connect(user='cj', password=mypw, dsn=cs)
```

See the example above for where to locate the file.

Another alternative is to use the Easy Connect syntax:

```
import oracledb

cs = "localhost:1521/orclpdb1"
c = oracledb.connect(user='cj', password=mypw, dsn=cs)
```